# KSH Conditional Query

Tags: ksh

I have the following snippet of code in a ksh script that I'm trying to understand...

```
if [ -f ${FILELIST} -a -s ${FILELIST} ]; then
......
fi
```

The first part is checking if a file exists at the name used in place of the variable FILELIST.  The second part is what is confusing to me.  I believe -a is checking for a symbolic link and -s is checking if the file size is greater than zero but there is no "AND" or "OR" clause linking the two items together.  Is this trying to check if the file exists or if the symbolic link exists with a size greater than zero?

Comment: I have a habit of running `ksh -n script.ksh` whenever I am testing things out, as it will check the syntax of your script and point out things to change.  Common recommendations are things like `warning: line 4: -a obsolete, use -e`.

Answer (score 3):

`-a` *is* the "and" joining the two queries. However, its use is deprecated (by the POSIX standard, at least) and could be replaced with:

```
if [ -f "$FILELIST" ] && [ -s "$FILELIST" ]; then
```

In `ksh` (where `-a` can also confusingly be used as an obsolete synonym for `-e`), you could also use

```
if [[ -f "$FILELIST" && -s "$FILELIST" ]]; then
```

The `test` command (i.e., `[`) does not recognize `&&` as an operator in place of `-a`, which is why the recommended POSIX-compatible replacement is to separate `test` commands joined by the shell `&&` operator.